# Does a Monster have to survive an attack to yield Tokyo?

Tags: king-of-tokyo

King of Tokyo has one of the most poorly written [rules](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/63033/king-of-tokyo-english-rules).

The rules state:

> If a Monster loses its last life({Heart}) it is out of the game.
>
> If you are attacked while in Tokyo and you don't want to be there anymore [...] **you can yield** to the Monster that attacked (he has to take your place). You still take the damage, however.
>
> If you are eliminated by an attack on Tokyo, the Monster who attacked you automatically takes control of Tokyo.
>
> **Yielding Tokyo / Flee:** A Monster can leave Tokyo (yield his place) to the Monster who just attacked him. If a card allows a monster to leave tokyo with no damage from an attack, the attacker still occupies Tokyo.
>
> **Eliminated:** When you have 0{Heart}.

**Does a Monster need to survive an attack to yield Tokyo?**

This is important for a card like:

> **(5) Burrowing**: Keep; Deal 1 extra damage on Tokyo.
>
> Deal 1 damage when yielding Tokyo to the monster taking it.

**Does a Monster eliminated by an attack deal 1 damage to the Monster that attacked them?**

Answer (score 6):

When a monster is eliminated while inside Tokyo, they do not yield. Look at the exact phrasing:

> If you are eliminated by an attack on Tokyo, the Monster who attacked
>   you automatically **takes control** of Tokyo.

The rules say "takes control of", not "is yielded," so no yielding happens and the extra damage from Burrowing doesn't occur. Thematically, this makes sense: the monster is dead, and its ability to burrow doesn't help. You aren't yielding to the attacking monster; you're yielding to the sweet embrace of death. (Death takes one damage.)

Comment: Not that i disagree with your interpretation, but does this come from a WizKid rep or FAQ?

Comment: Alas, no; I have but my own gray matter to support this answer.